# How to disable Task Manager with VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I've recently been trying to disable Task Manager on my computer. I've tried this code

```
strcomputer = "."
HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
comppath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
strEntryName = "DisableTaskMgr"
dwValue = "00000001" 
retval = objReg.SetDWordValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, comppath, strEntryName, dwValue)
Wscript.echo retval
```

But it hasn't worked. The reason is that I lack that folder (the "System" one). I've been told to create it myself, but since creating that folder for every computer I'll use this code for is pretty lengthy I want to know if there are methods to automatically create that folder. If that's not the case I'd like to know another method. If possible, I don't want to use admin privileges.

I've also tried this code on cmd by the way. Pretty similar, just wanted to point it out.

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /f /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001
```

---

UPDATE: I found the code eventually, and I've been recommended to post it.
It uses a `.bat` file instead of a `.vbs` one, but it's worth it. Also, you **must** run it as an administrator, or else it won't work

There are two codes. The first one I'll post will *disable* Task Manager, the second one will *re-enable* it (If you run the second one before, nothing bad should happen, though)

```
REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---

```
REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Comment: Without admin privileges, you can't manipulate the registry.

Comment: Do you know any methods that require admin privilege? I've tried using admin privileges but I haven't gotten any functioning code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works pretty well (Requires Admin):

```
Dim Shell, regCommand
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", ""
Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DisableTaskMgr", 1, "REG_DWORD"
```

Comment: I'll try it out (hopefully) soon and I'll let you know how it went

Comment: Didn't work. I'd need to make that folder so if you can create a code that does that it would probably work. I'm refering to the last folder (System) and the DisableTaskMgr file, I've tried this code and similar ones and I didn't have that folder by default so that would help me a lot

Comment: It tells me there`s an error. Specifically on Line 3 Character 1. Error 80070005. It has to do with WshShell.RegWrite. I know nothing else

Comment: I found an answer elsewhere buy I'll mark yours as a valid one

Comment: @nicochulo Can you please share the answer for this.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Of course! How can I direct message you to share the code? If you want to, I can also create one of those "already answered" questions and send you a link, or something like that

Comment: @nicochulo You can edit your question and add an update.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Fair enough, I'll do it asap

Answer (score 0):

`reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /f /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001`
WORKED LOL change from `00000001` to `00000000` to *en*able taskmgr

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please point out the difference, if any, from the solution added to the question or presented in iBug's answer.